# I want to calculate hours and minuts from my text lines

Tags: powershell

These are my two employees sajjad and hamid. The data i am providing here is in text file lines.

```
                     sajjad 127  9/18/2022 7:30:10 AM           1
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 8:24:51 AM           2
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:42:45 PM           1
                     sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:44:50 PM           1


                          Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:38:24 AM           1
                            Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:42:09 AM           1
                            Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 3:28:54 PM           2
                          Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 5:36:22 PM           2
```

I am new in coding and want to develop a script that should read each employee 1st attendance record  (which is in my case check in) and last record (which is in my case check out) like in my text lines there are multiple records but i want to take 1st and last record of each employee and perform the calculations for hours minutes and seconds and export results to csv file

Employee check-in timing--->              **sajjad 127  9/18/2022 7:30:10 AM           1**

Employee checkout timing--->              **sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:44:50 PM           1**

Employee sajjad date 9/18/2022 working hours are 7hours 14Minutes 40Seconds

Employee check-in timing--->          **Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:38:24 AM           1**

Employee checkout timing--->          **Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 5:36:22 PM           2**

Employee hamid date 9/1/2022 working hours are 8hours 57Minutes 58Seconds

Comment: `[datetime]'9/1/2022 5:36:22 PM' - [datetime]'9/1/2022 8:38:24 AM'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently i dont have any code, as i have tried on  google but not found any script

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I use a regular expression to collect the data in the textfile and then do the calculations.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
$data=@"
                     **sajjad 127  9/18/2022 7:30:10 AM           1**
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 8:24:51 AM           2
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:42:45 PM           1
                     **sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:44:50 PM           1**


                          **Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:38:24 AM           1**
                            Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:42:09 AM           1
                            Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 3:28:54 PM           2
                          **Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 5:36:22 PM           2**
"@



$datelog = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[datetime,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,psobject]]]::new()

foreach($row in ($data -split [environment]::NewLine)) {
    
    if($row -match '\W*\**(.*) \d+\W+(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [AP]M)\W+(\d+)\**$') {
        $DAY=([datetime]$matches[2]).date
        $time = [datetime]($matches[2])
        $person = $matches[1]
        if (-not $datelog.containskey($DAY)) {
            $datelog.add($DAY,[Dictionary[string,psobject]]::new())
        }
        if($datelog[$DAY].containskey($person)) {
            $datelog[$DAY][$person].Endtime=$time
        } else {
            $datelog[$DAY].add($person,[pscustomobject]@{Starttime = $time;Endtime = $null})
        }
    }
}

$exportlist = @()
foreach ($day in $datelog.keys) {
    $day.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
    foreach($p in $datelog[$day].keys) {
        $elapsed =$datelog[$day][$p].endtime - $datelog[$day][$p].starttime
        $elapsedString="{0:d2}h, {1:d2}m, {2:d2}s" -f $elapsed.Hours,$elapsed.Minutes,$elapsed.Seconds
        $exportlist += [pscustomobject]@{
            Day = $day.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Person = $p
            Start = $datelog[$day][$p].starttime.tostring("HH:mm")
            End = $datelog[$day][$p].endtime.tostring("HH:mm")
            Elapsed = $elapsedString
        }
    }
}
$exportlist|export-csv -Path c:\temp\export.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

Result (export.csv):

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Day";"Person";"Start";"End";"Elapsed"
"2022-09-18";"sajjad";"07:30";"14:44";"07h, 14m, 40s"
"2022-09-01";"Abdul Hamid";"08:38";"17:36";"08h, 57m, 58s"
```

Comment: after executing your script i am getting this error on PowerShell       "Unable to find type [Dictionary].
At line:25 char:31
+             $datelog.add($DAY,[Dictionary[string,psobject]]::new())
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dictionary:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:27 char:12
+         if($datelog[$DAY].containskey($person) 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException"

Comment: i dont know why this error is appearing @pelin72 please help i will be very thank full to you please

Comment: in your regex you added the ** which is not in my text it was only mentioned to made bold the lines which i was needed to calculate so this ragex will not work '\W*\**(.*) \d+\W+(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [AP]M)\W+(\d+)\**$')

Comment: my sample text file is this sajjad 127  9/18/2022 7:30:10 AM           1
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 8:24:51 AM           2
                       sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:42:45 PM           1
                     sajjad 127  9/18/2022 2:44:50 PM           1


                          Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:38:24 AM           1
                          Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 8:42:09 AM           1
                         Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 3:28:54 PM           2
                        Abdul Hamid 128   9/1/2022 5:36:22 PM           2  without **

Comment: Sorry, I have added on line at the top ```using namespace System.Collections.Generic```.
It is required. The regex handle ** or no ** it should not matter.

Comment: Yes @pelin72 thank you very much i got the results on powershell screen, i do want to export it on csv file i inserted | export-csv -path c:\result.csv but it not worked how to fix this issue please help

Comment: Bundle of Thanks it worked for me i successfully exported the file in csv

Comment: i clicked on upvote option but i dont know how to mark your answer as an accepted, can u please share the steps for marking ur answer?